# Titanium complilation error "Failed to compile java source files"

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-modules, titanium-android

I am developing a titanium android module.
After lot of research i finally set up the environment for module development.
I got successful module build.
But when i add the module to android application "Failed to compile java source files" error occure.
Follwing are my error log

`[INFO] :   Building Java source files: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\javac.exe "-J-Xmx256M" "-encoding" "utf8" "-bootclasspath" "C:\android-sdk-win\platforms\android-19\android.jar;C:\Users\Akihl\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\kroll-v8.jar;C:\Users\Akihl\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-analytics.jar;C:\Users\Akihl\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\aps-analytics.jar;C:\Users\Akihl\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-android.jar;C:\Users\Akihl\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\jaxen-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Akihl\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\ti-commons-codec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Akihl\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\kroll-common.jar;C:\Users\Akihl\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\titanium.jar;C:\Users\Akihl\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-app.jar;C:\Users\Akihl\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-ui.jar;C:\Users\Akihl\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\nineoldandroids-appc-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Akihl\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-filesystem.jar;C:\Users\Akihl\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-media.jar;C:\Users\Akihl\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-appcompat.jar;C:\Users\Akihl\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\android-support-v4.jar;C:\Users\Akihl\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar;C:\Users\Akihl\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-locale.jar;C:\Users\Akihl\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-network.jar;C:\Users\Akihl\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\thirdparty.jar;C:\Users\Akihl\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-xml.jar;C:\Users\Akihl\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\moduleApplication\modules\android\com.example\1.0.0\example_module.jar;C:\Users\Akihl\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\kroll-apt.jar;C:\Users\Akihl\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA\android\lib\titanium-verify.jar;R.class;ApplicationStylesheet.class;AssetCryptImpl.class;ModuleapplicationActivity.class;ModuleapplicationAppInfo.class;ModuleapplicationApplication.class" "-d" "C:\Users\Akihl\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\moduleApplication\build\android\bin\classes" "-proc:none" "-target" "1.6" "-source" "1.6" "@C:\Users\Akihl\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\moduleApplication\build\android\java-sources.txt"
[ERROR] :  Failed to compile Java source files:
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1`

### My developement environment

jdk-jdk1.6.0_25

titanium sdk-3.5.1.GA

os-win 7

ant-1.9.4

python 3.X

Anyone please help.
Thaks in advance...

Comment: there should also be a javac trace somewhere in the logs. Please post that as well

Comment: i got the solution.It was because of bootstrap class was not generated.